# How to create table with 2 rows and different no of columns

Tags: html, html-table, multiple-columns

I want to create a table, which will have 2 rows. First row contains 2 columns of equal size and second column should contain 3 columns of equal size.

Is it possible to design this type of table in HTML?

I don’t want to use nested tables; using single table can it be achievable?

[image]

Comment: why a downvote for this question? downvoter, could you please explain?

Comment: why negative points??? Did i ask anything wrong?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because there's no indication of research effort, you're not showing what you've tried yourself before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border=1 width=200>
    <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents

```
<table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eJ7ts/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<table width=300 >
    <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

little css

```
 td
{
    border: 2px solid #000;
    height:50px;
}
```

fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Ah9AE/